# Flash - go to another "child" in another scene

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've got 3 scenes, in every scene is one layer (parent), in every layer (parent in scenes) is one more layer (child), here is for example 5 layers. 
In every scenes, I have got menu with 3 url to scene.

Example:

Scene 1:
I roll out menu, I choose url 1, show scene 1, frame 2 (child).

```
pietro1.gotoAndStop(2);
```

I roll out menu, I choose url 2, show scene 2, frame 1 (child).

```
gotoAndStop(1, "Scena 2");
```

I'm in link 2(Scene 2), I want to back to:
Scene 1, layer 1 (parent), frame 2 (child)

How can I do it?

Comment: Could you clarify your layer setup, it sounds a little confusing the way it is written. Perhaps just use an outline format to describe your scene and layer structure.

Comment: Here is setup layer: http://bankfotek.pl/image/1786428

Maybe I send to you my flash file *.fla?